# How to validate data during inference using tfx / tfdv / tensorflow serving?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tfx

I'm building a tfx pipeline and using tensorflow serving to serve my model. I save the signature with `model.save(...)`.

So far I was able to use the transform layer to transform the feature before prediction with `tf_transform_output.transform_features_layer()` (see my code below).

However, I'm wondering how one can detect anomalies in the input data? For instance, I don't want to predict for an input value that is too far away from the distribution that a feature was trained with before.

The `tfdv` library offers functions like `generate_statistics_from_[csv|dataframe|tfrecord]` but I was not able to find any good example to generate statistics for serialized `tf.Example`s (or something that is not saved in a file, like csv, tfrecords etc.).

I'm aware of the following [example in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/get_started):

```
   import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
   import tfx_bsl
   import pyarrow as pa
   decoder = tfx_bsl.coders.example_coder.ExamplesToRecordBatchDecoder()
   example = decoder.DecodeBatch([serialized_tfexample])
   options = tfdv.StatsOptions(schema=schema)
   anomalies = tfdv.validate_instance(example, options)
```

But in this example `serialized_tfexample` is a string, whereas in my code below the argument `serialized_tf_examples` is a Tensor of strings.

Sorry if this is an obvious question. I spent all day to find a solution without success. Maybe I'm getting this all thing wrong. Maybe this is not the right place to put validations. So my more generalized question is actually: How do you validate incoming input data before prediction when you serve a model, which you created through a tfx pipeline, in production?
I'm thankful for any lead into the right direction.

Here is my code to which I want to add validation:

```
...

tf_transform_output = tft.TFTransformOutput(...)
model.tft_layer = tf_transform_output.transform_features_layer()

@tf.function(input_signature=[
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string, name='examples')
])
def serve_tf_examples_fn(serialized_tf_examples):

    #### How can I generate stats and validate serialized_tf_examples? ###
    #### Is this the right place? ###

    feature_spec = tf_transform_output.raw_feature_spec()
    feature_spec.pop(TARGET_LABEL)
    parsed_features = tf.io.parse_example(serialized_tf_examples, feature_spec)

    transformed_features = model.tft_layer(parsed_features)

    return model(transformed_features)

...

model.save(serving_model_dir,
           save_format='tf',
           signatures={
               'serving_default': serve_tf_examples_fn
           })
```

Comment: I have a similar question. Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: @kennysong Unfortunately not yet. I'm still on trying to figure it out. The only recommendation I got so far is to use batch prediction and store the input data in files instead of using online prediction.

Comment: I came looking for help with Batch Prediction, in hopes of answering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65525944/how-do-i-get-a-dataframe-or-database-write-from-tfx-bulkinferrer If the person recommending @JohnTartu use batch prediction has experience with it, they might be able to pick up a few points there...